# How does dns.resolver.Resolver() find nameservers?

Tags: python, dns

On a windows machine I'm having an issue where the Resolver() uses a nameserver which is not a dns server. I don't know where it gets the server ip from.

python code:

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
print(my_resolver.nameservers)
['<ip address that is not a dns server>', '<dns server>', '<dns server>']
```

running ipconfig /all does not return the first item in the nameservers list it only shows the "working" dns servers

i tried looking in the registry at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, but the wrong server is not there either

my question is where does dns.resolver.Resolver() gets the dns server ips from on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found it in the source code in the resolver.py script:

in the read_registry function it looks in the registry under HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters and then under
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces and i think it iterates over the interfaces and adds them the dns servers to the list if it finds any

i had an old connection stuck here (with a virtual interface i guess thats not in use anymore) so i just deleted the key from the registry and now it doesn't add that ip